# Change the Date and Time in Date Picker based on Time zone

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using Ant Design (3.x) in my react application. It's a timezone based application. we have timezone list as dropdown in the top bar. when we select any timezone, all the date and time fields ( Table column data, Tooltip, summary data, etc...) in the app are changing accordingly.

HKT Time:

[image]

IST Time:

[image]

But, Inputting date and time in DatePicker is not changing based on Timezone

HKT Time:

[image]

IST Time:

[image]

It is only taking the computer's timezone (My guess). I am using moment timezone package for converting date and time based on Timezone. This package only antd is using.

Comment: Which library you are using for `DatePicker`?

Comment: I am using Ant Design (https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#header)

Comment: How are the other values changing in your page upon changing your timezone selection? Are the components listening to drop-down change and update dates inside them with the selected timezone with the help of **moment-timezone**?

Comment: Yes @PrathapReddy, We are using redux to store the timezone globally. Whenever timezone change in the dropdown, we will update the store. By using moment-timezone, we are changing the values everywhere.

Comment: Gocha. For other components you are explicitly changing date values by using `moment-timezone`. Whereas the `Datepicker` don't have any such `prop` to pass the selected timezone. I have added my answer, Hope it helps 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting/updating the timezone upon **drop-down value change** with `moment-timezone` (call the `setDefault` with specific timezone value upon drop-down change). For example,

```
moment.tz.setDefault("America/New_York");
```

**Ant design** `DatePicker` is picking the timezone as per `moment.tz.setDefault` - [CodeSandbox example for the same](https://codesandbox.io/embed/6j3rn31zw?codemirror=1)

For additional information on `default timezone` check the [official docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/default-timezone)

Answer (score 0):

With `dayjs` the accepted solution didn't work for us. We wanted our date to be displayed in UTC and ended up making a custom format like

```
format={date => date.utc().format("MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm:ss")}
```

You could do something similar with a timezone like

```
  format={date => date.tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm:ss")}
```

Note: you will need to add the utc and timezone plugins

```
import utc = from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';
import timezone = from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone';

dayjs.extend(utc)
dayjs.extend(timezone)
```

Comment: This results in UTC time showed on the input after selection but the picker is still in current timezone for me. I mean, if I click 10:10, the selection will show 9:10 (utc), but the need for me is for the picker to work as if current timezone was UCT. Is there a way to achieve this?